# C++ Fastest text line comparisons with n-Gram? Use strings, char*, vectors?

Tags: c++, string, vector, large-data

so I'm currently writing something which would compare columns in a data table. So I basically need Rows, Columns, and all are text read in from a .csv file.

The issue currently is how long it takes to process. I have duplicate code in C# which uses a 'DataTable' with Rows and Columns which takes around 13 seconds to process 1500 lines of text.
My c++ program uses 'vector < vector  >' as the table, and processes only 175 lines of text in this amount of time.
Algorithms are the same from what I can see, but I'm guessing it's something related to the data types I"m using in c++ that makes this slower.

Does anyone have ideas on the cause?

```
//C++
void CheckColumn(int colNum)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < RowCount; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < RowCount; j++)
        {
            nGram(Data[colNum][i], Data[colNum][j], 3);
        }
    }
}
double nGram(string one, string two, int count)
{
    //Change to uppercase
    transform(one.begin(), one.end(), one.begin(), toupper);
    transform(two.begin(), two.end(), two.begin(), toupper);

    //Set the first string to be the shorter one
    if (one.size() > two.size())
    {
        string temp = one;
        one = two;
        two = temp;
    }

    //If nGram number is larger than the shortest string, set the nGram number to that length
    if (one.size() < count)
    {
        count = one.size();
    }

    //Add matches
    double weight = 0;
    double possibleMatches = (2 * two.size() - 2 * count + 2) / 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < (one.size() - count + 1); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < (two.size() - count + 1); j++)
        {
            if (one.substr(i, count) == two.substr(j, count))
            {
                weight += 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    //Check for indivisible situations and otherwise calculate the weight
    if ((possibleMatches == 0) || (weight == 0))
    {
        weight = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        weight = weight / possibleMatches;
    }

    return weight;
}


//C#
void CompareColumn(int colNum)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < table.Rows.Count; j++)
        {
            StringFunctions.nGram(table.Rows[i][colNum].ToString(), table.Rows[j][colNum].ToString(), 3);
        }
    }
}
public double nGram(string one, string two, int count)
{
    //Change to uppercase
    one = one.ToUpper();
    two = two.ToUpper();

    //Set the first string to be the shorter one
    if (one.Length > two.Length)
    {
        string temp = one;
        one = two;
        two = temp;
    }

    //If nGram number is larger than the shortest string, set the nGram number to that length
    if (one.Length < count)
    {
        count = one.Length;
    }

    //Add matches
    double doubleMatch = 0;
    double possibleMatches = (2 * two.Length - 2 * count + 2)/2;
    for (int i = 0; i < (one.Length - count + 1); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < (two.Length - count + 1); j++)
        {
            if (one.Substring(i, count) == two.Substring(j, count))
            {
                doubleMatch += 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    //Check for indivisible situations and otherwise calculate the weight
    if ((possibleMatches == 0) || (doubleMatch == 0))
    {
        doubleMatch = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        doubleMatch = doubleMatch / possibleMatches;
    }
    return doubleMatch;
}
```

Comment: The first issue I see is you're passing by value vs. reference. You're wasting time with copy construction. The first thing I would suggest is change the signature of your nGram to read ```ngram(string&, string&, count)

Comment: Have you profiled to see what is taking the most time?

Comment: You should also make sure you are doing your testing/profiling with optimized code.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the suggestions. I switched everything to use a char* array and all my methods take pointers instead of values.

I'm now processing 781406.25 n-gram comparisons/second in my c++ while my c# was doing about 91875 n-gram comparisons/second.

I may try to switch this back to string vectors with the suggestions you've provided but for the time being, I can process a huge column of 155000 rows comparing each to all other rows in about 4hours which is a good start. My c# program would've taken 1.5days and seems to max the CPU while my c++ program only uses 25% of the CPU.

Comment: @ Retired Ninja - I also was running this with optimized code and profiling previously, but the combination of using strings and passing values directly seems to be the main issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`double nGram(string one, string two, int count)`

Without diving into your code too much, the method above is one of the first issues I noticed. In C++ you can pass a value by copy, reference, or pointer. The method you're using is by copy and creates overhead when you have a method being called a lot.

To illistrate take the following class.

```
class CopyMe
{

public:
    CopyMe();
    CopyMe(const CopyMe&m);
    ~CopyMe();
};


CopyMe::CopyMe()
{
    std::cout << "Created! Instance @ Location: " << this << std::endl;
}

CopyMe::CopyMe(const CopyMe& m)
{
    std::cout << "Copy! Instance @ Location: " << &m << " New Location: " << this << std::endl;
}

CopyMe::~CopyMe()
{
    std::cout << "Deleted! Instance @ Location: " << this << std::endl;
}
```

and the following short main.

```
void SayHelloToMyLittleFriendViaCopy(CopyMe aCopy)
{
    std::cout << "Inside " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}

void SayHelloToMyLittleFriendViaReference(CopyMe& aReference)
{
    std::cout << "Inside " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    CopyMe me;
    SayHelloToMyLittleFriendViaCopy(me);

    SayHelloToMyLittleFriendViaReference(me);
    return 0;
}
```

If you run the code above you will get the following output. *Note* Your memory locations will be different!

```
Created! Instance @ Location: 0x7fff5fbff7d8
Copy! Instance @ Location: 0x7fff5fbff7d8 New Location: 0x7fff5fbff7d0
Inside void SayHelloToMyLittleFriendViaCopy(CopyMe)
Deleted! Instance @ Location: 0x7fff5fbff7d0
Inside void SayHelloToMyLittleFriendViaReference(CopyMe &)
Deleted! Instance @ Location: 0x7fff5fbff7d8
```

If you compare the two calls you will notice that the call to `SayHelloToMyLittleFriendViaCopy` has overhead in that it creates a copy, runs the method, and then deletes the temporary object it created. In contrast the call to `SayHelloToMyLittleFriendViaReference` incurs no such cost in that the function is called an no temporary copy is created. The above may be confusing in that the object destructor is called at the end of the example. however, that is not caused by the function, but the fact that we are exerting the main method and our initial object is destroyed.

If this is the first time you have heard of pass by reference you can think of it as passing pointer. However, instead of you having to dereference the object, the compiler adds the sugar for you.

However, if you pass by reference there is the possibility that the method could changes the state of the object. If that is something you want to avoid you can still pass by reference, but with a const reference. If that is what you're after then your signature should be

```
double nGram(const string& one,const string& two, int count)
```

Comment: Making them const references might help with speed, but the first thing done in the function is to convert the strings to uppercase meaning a copy would need to be made then.  Passing by value when you need a copy is not a bad thing.

Answer (score 0):

I did a combination of things to resolve this and I'll definitely try testing a few scenarios.

I was using the optimization build, but the fact that I was copying my string values to my function was probably the main issue.
I'm currently using a character array, which allows me to speed up the n-Gram process a little bit. Since I go through character by character in the compare part, I only have to check the first character when the whole n-Gram wouldn't be a match. So for example, comparing "ABC" to "BBC", I know I don't have to look at the second or third character to see if the tri-gram is a match.

Additionally, the main problem seems to have been not utilizing pointers. Passing char* pointers seems to increase the process the most. I will try moving back to strings with pointers instead of char pointers, however I'm still guessing characters are the way to go.

Thanks everyone for the help!